# How to disable bxSlider on mouseleave?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bxslider

Is it possible to deactivate the plugin 'bxSlider' on mouseleave?

```
$('.post').mouseenter(function() {   
         $('.content .bxSlider').each(function(){
             $(this).bxSlider({auto: 'true'});
         });
     }).mouseleave(function() {
         // ??
});
```

Please advice...

Comment: Updated my answer again, not sure if you get a notification for that...

Comment: Yeah, I was refreshing each minute :) Thanks for the notification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you want to stop it? Do you want it to auto-advance only while hovered?
Looking at the [options](http://bxslider.com/options) I belive you can do this:

```
$('.content .bxSlider').each(function(){
         $(this).bxSlider();
});

$('.post').mouseenter(function() {   
         $('.content .bxSlider').each(function(){
             $(this).startAuto();
         });
     }).mouseleave(function() {   
         $('.content .bxSlider').each(function(){
             $(this).stopAuto();
         });
});
```

Naturally this code could be optimised a bit, maybe with some variables to reduce the number of dom searches, but I think this is what you're after :)

**EDIT**

Right so the above doesn't work. The public function isn't recognised unless the slider object is a variable. I'm not sure why but here's how I got around it:

```
var sliders = []; // store for the sliders

$('.content .bxSlider').each(function() {
    sliders.push($(this).bxSlider({auto: false})); // create a slider and store it
});

$('.post').mouseenter(function() {   
         $.each(sliders, function(i){
             sliders[i].startAuto(); // start each slider
         });
     }).mouseleave(function() {   
         $.each(sliders, function(i){
             sliders[i].stopAuto(); // stop each slider
         });
});​
```

And here it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/KBfx9/
Hope that helps!

**EDIT 2**
*Solution for triggering nested slideshow:*

The previous solution was to trigger multiple slideshows simultaneously. I have amended it here: http://jsfiddle.net/KBfx9/1/ to trigger the nested slideshow. **Note:** I've just use the class `.content` as my identifier instead of post because in my example the latter is unneeded. Additionally I've used the container's `index()` to identify the relevant slider since this will work in the page the OP has linked to (in the comments below).

Hope this sorts it for you :)

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this before and just tried it again, but startAuto and stopAuto are not defined as functions.

Comment: By the way, I'm using the latest version for both bxSlider and jQuery... any other ways you think can help on this? :)

Comment: yeah, sorry seen my error. Will edit my answer with a working one :)

Comment: Thank you very much, it's close to what I needed, but I need to disable the plug-in on mouseleave so it will reset on hover, there are some conflicts on my page which this will solve it.

Comment: what do you mean 'reset on hover'? Do you want the sliders to start from the first slide whenever you hover `.post`? If so just add `sliders[i].goToSlide(0);` before `sliders[i].startAuto();`

Comment: or you can just add it to the `mouseleave` function after `sliders[i].stopAuto();` to reset on mouse leave

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. Please take a look here: http://sneakyrascal.com/test/ when you hover a box, the slider will activate, and if you stay until the auto play starts and then go hover on other boxes you see that they're not working. This happens after an 'auto' starts on one of the boxes...

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks a million for sharing your knowledge :)

Comment: Updated the link, although there is one thing, `sliders[i].goToSlide(0);` creates a bug as when you mouveleave and mouseenter the slider for that box will not work again, [here](http://sneakyrascal.com/test2) is with the goToSlide code as in your code  When I remove it like [here](http://sneakyrascal.com/test) it works just fine.

Comment: Do you have any hints about this? I haven't gotten around it yet.

Comment: your code is pretty lengthy and probably should be optimised. Since the code I supplied works in my basic example I suspect its one of the other functions. Try moving the slider code so it only runs when the slider container is visible. I've also optimised my code for you: http://jsfiddle.net/KBfx9/2/ . If you still have trouble I'd raise a new question and link it to this one. I'll keep an eye out for it :)

Comment: I've added your code, but still when I hover for the second time it will stuck... but the other boxes will work for the first hover. I will create a new question for this and let you know, if you have time please check it so I can use your help in the morning, it's quite urgent. Many thanks!! [(the link is updated)] http://sneakyrascal.com/test/

Comment: I've fixed the problem. It was a fadeOut call in the mouseleave that made a conflict... now it works fine(updated the link), but a bit buggy still, I will optimize my code as you suggested and see how that goes. Thanks again for your help :)